# dropdown list value when selected then it sets another column value in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, powerapp

I am new in using SharePoint List.I have list created with two columns in same sharepoint list Column A(Text) and B(currrency). I want to set value of column B when Column A value is selected of same ID value of Item.

A B

abc  $12

xyz  $2

pqr  $20

Please give me solution to use this list to use in powerApps for calculations

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Are you using this list in another list as a lookup?

Comment: No, I have just created one simple list with 2 columns and 15 items for both columns. I am trying to create calculator application.so If item abc is selected from column A in powerapps then it will consider value $12 from column B. I have no idea how to use lookup. can you please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerApps itself to set the field value. Check this:https://wonderlaura.com/2018/06/01/powerapps-set-a-field-value/

Or you can use a SharePoint calculated column to show the value. The formula will be like

=IF( A="abc" , 12, IF( A="xyz", 2 , IF( A="pqr", 20 , [other value you need])))